# How is an authentication follow designed?

Tags: security, software-design

For many applications that I've ever worked on. After logging successfully and session's still active, if users try to access signin/signup page by directly using browser address bar, they'll be redirected to dashboard or home page. I just follows some existing applications such as Goolge perhaps.

But what's the main reason of this flow? Does it raise any security risks if users can still access signin/sigup while their sessions are still active?

Comment: This is subjective and depends on your interpretation of the intent of the user. Does loading the sign-up page means they want to make a new account? Does it mean they made a mistake and just mean to log in? Both interpretations are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision to have separate login page or redirection of user to another page depends on the use case or requirement that you have for your website.  It is directly related towards the functionality you want to provide to users.

It is mainly for bringing functional separation such that the login page is specifically for logging in and dashboard page or home page is to show the the account details or other related information of your home page. It also can be used for security purpose.

Functionally, having user login and dashboard page on same page can have its own challenges based on the other processing that is being done by you as per your use case. Consider a scenario where an email shall be sent whenever you login and also some additional processing is done based on the login procedure. Each refresh on the posted page would log the user back in. In such a case, every refreshment of the dashboard page would trigger an email and also does additional processing which may not be desired. In the perspective of security, based on your requirement, you may redirect URL based on [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)(Post-Redirect-Get) pattern to a restricted page or guest user page rather than having the main home page when an unauthenticated user logins or based on the subscription type of user.

It should also be noted that having a login mechanism integrated into the main page also has an advantage based on your website requirement as it provides the ability to login without losing the context of what the user is doing which is purely dependent on the requirement for your website. However, a separate login page has the advantage of being easier to implement and also for the pages that have sensitive information, you can simply redirect to the login page, rather than having to worry about rendering UI without the context of a valid session.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a usability feature than a security one. Developers put a bit of additional effort to implement stuff like this. [Here is an example how they do it](https://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into "OAUTH2" or similar authorization (beware not authentication) software, that might spread the light its about tokens and who might use them where and when. (pretty shady that's why im gonna leave that link here but you should really dig deeper for yourself)

https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/system-administration/using-oauth2